# Autolayout with dynamic specified spacing between views

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I have been working with Autolayout for a while now and knew pretty much inside out of how it works. One thing I cannot figure out is the number in the visual representation.

For example, `V:|-(20)-[someView]` I want something more along the line of `V:|-(x)-[someView]`.

I do not need the number to change after the the constraints are established. But given that I work with many constraints at the same time and I am trying to find out what is the best spacing for best UX. Instead of going through and replace each `20`, I just want to just set `x` to the desired number and rebuild the app. (I know find/replace works but that is not robust and can easily create an unintended change if you are not careful)

The *best* I can come up with is using `stringWithFormat` but that increases the cluster in the code and not very scalable when it comes to complex views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `metrics`is exactly what you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
NSDictionary *views = @{@"blueView" : blueView};
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"offset" : @(40)};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-offset-[blueView]-offset-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-offset-[blueView]-offset-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

Comment: Indeed it is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! If it is just a simple number, this works too `@40` instead of `@(40)`